# R - Position of a word if it occurs between two words in character vector

Tags: r

I have a sample xml input character vector as follows. I do not use xml parsing functions because the xml document is not completely valid:

```
x1 <- readLines("test.xml)
x1
<important>
<hdtitle>Important:</hdtitle>
<stepgrp type="unordered-bullet">
<step>
Ensure the dark link is facing up.
</step>
<step>
If using the chain and sprockets again, align the darkened
link with the marked sprockets made during disassembly.
</step>
</stepgrp>
</important>
Install the drive chain to the drive sprocket and the driven
sprocket.
</step>
```

I want to find position of `</important>` between `</step>` and consecutive `</step>`based on the condition that:
1)`<step>` doesn't occur between the position of `</step>` and consecutive `</step>`

My desired output is as follows:

```
<important>
<hdtitle>Important:</hdtitle>
<stepgrp type="unordered-bullet">
<step>
Ensure the dark link is facing up.
</step>
<step>
If using the chain and sprockets again, align the darkened
link with the marked sprockets made during disassembly.
</step>
</stepgrp>
</important><step>
Install the drive chain to the drive sprocket and the driven
sprocket.
</step>
```

I am adding `<step>` after `</important>` if the above condition satisfies.

Comment: I have edited the questions. I know i can use grep for finding position but how do i find if the word exists between those numbers/positions.

Comment: You could use `substr` and then `grep` the sub-string for what you are looking for. If the string doesn't exist, R will return `character(0)` from the grep call.

Comment: @small_data88 I don't quite understand that. Could you pls explain in detail?

Comment: Okay, assuming x1 is a string representation of the XML, you could first split the string up on the first "</step>", `theSplit<-strsplit(x1, "</step>", fixed=TRUE)`, then grep the second and third lines of the string, since that is what you want to examine, `grep("</step>",substr(theSplit[[1]][2:3], 1, 1000))`. The grep call will return the indices of where the regex worked or `character(0)` if nothing exists. I randomly used 1000 as the stop to ensure that I hit the entire string. Not sure if this is a complete solution, but hopefully a good start. :) Employ if condition on output of grep.

Answer (score 0):

```
imp_end <- grep("<\\/important>", x)
step_start <- grep("<step>", x)
step_end <- grep("<\\/step>", x)
imp_intervals <- cut(imp_end, step_end)
step_start_intervals <- na.omit(cut(step_start, step_end))
valid <- na.omit(imp_intervals[!imp_intervals %in% step_start_intervals])
indx <- na.omit(imp_end[imp_intervals == valid])
x[indx] <- gsub("^(<\\/important>)$", "\\1<step>", x[indx])
x
#  [1] "<important>"                                                 
#  [2] "<hdtitle>Important:</hdtitle>"                               
#  [3] "<stepgrp type=\"unordered-bullet\">"                         
#  [4] "<step>"                                                      
#  [5] "Ensure the dark link is facing up."                          
#  [6] "</step>"                                                     
#  [7] "<step>"                                                      
#  [8] "If using the chain and sprockets again, align the darkened"  
#  [9] "link with the marked sprockets made during disassembly."     
# [10] "</step>"                                                     
# [11] "</stepgrp>"                                                  
# [12] "</important><step>"                                          
# [13] "Install the drive chain to the drive sprocket and the driven"
# [14] "sprocket."                                                   
# [15] "</step>"
```

I used `cut` to create intervals for the lines. I'm assuming that the data is vertical as laid out in the example. Then with `valid`, I looked for the locations of `</important>` that were between `"</step>"` and also having no `"<step>"` strings in the same interval. I tried to decipher your rule logic, let me know if it is what you were looking for.

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text='
<important>
<hdtitle>Important:</hdtitle>
<stepgrp type="unordered-bullet">
<step>
Ensure the dark link is facing up.
</step>
<step>
If using the chain and sprockets again, align the darkened
link with the marked sprockets made during disassembly.
</step>
</stepgrp>
</important>
Install the drive chain to the drive sprocket and the driven
sprocket.
</step>', sep="\n", stringsAsFactors=F)
x <- df$V1
```